# HttpUrlConnection ответ от сервера

Tags: java, android, сервер, request, httpurlconnection

Я отправляю пост-запрос на сервер, в ответ сервер мне возвращает данные вида "e72616a827", которые я использую в следующем запросе:
[http://сайт?value=e72616a827](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82?value=e72616a827), но дело в том, что когда я отправляю запрос по этому адресу, мне приходит совсем не то, что нужно, но если я перезапущу программу и укажу во втором запросе прошлые данные: [http://сайт?value=e72616a827](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82?value=e72616a827), то все проходит нормально и приходит то что нужно, не понимаю в чем проблема, спасибо.

**Update**: подозрение на то, что второй запрос происходит слишком быстро и данные еще не успевают обработаться, можно ли поставить задержку между запросами?

Comment: программа работает на андроид?

Comment: ага, я только что проверил, поставил задержку между запросами Thread.sleep(5000) и все выполнилось как надо, можно ли так делать, если у меня это все выполняется в AsyncTask?

Comment: @SWR, лучше всего спросить тех, кто делает бэкенд, что за дела? :) Потому что так не должно быть.